# Sorting Featured Posts (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, post, sorting, wordpress-featured-image

I can display posts from featured category like so:

```
query_posts('tag=featured');
```

... but is it possible to further sort it using a dropdown/select menu:

```
<select name="">
  <option value="reviews">Reviews</option>
  <option value="articles">Articles</option>
  <option value="interviews">Interviews</option>
</select>
```

... so when one of the option is selected, how do I modify the original query (which would be now: `query_posts('tag=featured+option');`) posted above to show the matching posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query_posts('tag=featured,reviews');
```

So something like (you need to sanitize this)

```
$tags = array('featured', $_POST['selectbox']);
$query_posts_string = 'tag=' . join(',', $tags);
query_posts($query_posts_string);
```